# Does Youtube use <iframe> or <video> for the videos on their own domain?

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, html5-video

If not, how do they implement their videos? I am specifically trying to access the `playbackRate` property on a non-embedded youtube video for a chrome extension.

Comment: Right click -> inspect element = magic

Answer (score 2):

You could inspect their code.
If the browser has HTML5 then it uses `<video>` (with a blob URL !) otherwise it will use Flash.

Answer (score -1):

They use the `<video>` tag if your browser implements it, if not they use flash. You can check it by looking at the source code of a video page.